# Azure planned maintenance notification disparity

Tags: azure

We have our servers on Azure. And recently we got a mail notification for planned maintenance. But, on checking the dashboard, it shows no planned maintenance activity was planned.

However, when I open a single VM's dashboard, it shows messages related to maintenance.
It's not feasible for me to open each and every VM and check that message.

Is it just me or someone else is also facing the same issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just you - this just happened to us as well. In our case, VM blades showed planned maintenance 24-36 hours before we received an email notification. In that same time period, the ['Planned Maintenance' blade](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Health/AzureHealthBrowseBlade/plannedMaintenance/navigateTo/plannedMaintenance) did not show any upcoming maintenance.

This morning, after receiving formal email notification, the 'Planned Maintenance' blade properly showed the upcoming maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it just me or someone else is also facing the same issue?

No, not just you.

Other's VMs in that region which need maintenance will get the same message as you.

As David said, we can find [the message](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Health/AzureHealthBrowseBlade/plannedMaintenance/navigateTo/plannedMaintenance) here:

[image]

Maybe we should redeploy your VMs.

If the maintenance does not require a reboot, Azure uses in-place migration to pause the VM while the host is updated.

If maintenance requires a reboot, you get a notice of when the maintenance is planned. In these cases, you are given a time window where you can start the maintenance yourself, when it works for you.

More information about handling planned maintenance, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/Linux/maintenance-notifications).

Answer (score 0):

### AzureRM PowerShell

You can use Azure Powershell to see when VMs are scheduled for maintenance. Planned maintenance information is available from the Get-AzureRmVM cmdlet when you use the -status parameter.

`Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName rgName -Name vmName -Status`

You can also get the maintenance status for all VMs in a resource group by using Get-AzureRmVM and not specifying a VM.

`Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName rgName -Status`

The following PowerShell function takes your subscription ID and prints out a list of VMs that are scheduled for maintenance.

```
function MaintenanceIterator
{
    Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $args[0]

    $rgList= Get-AzureRmResourceGroup 

    for ($rgIdx=0; $rgIdx -lt $rgList.Length ; $rgIdx++)
    {
        $rg = $rgList[$rgIdx]        
    $vmList = Get-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName 
        for ($vmIdx=0; $vmIdx -lt $vmList.Length ; $vmIdx++)
        {
            $vm = $vmList[$vmIdx]
            $vmDetails = Get-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Status
              if ($vmDetails.MaintenanceRedeployStatus )
            {
                Write-Output "VM: $($vmDetails.Name)  IsCustomerInitiatedMaintenanceAllowed: $($vmDetails.MaintenanceRedeployStatus.IsCustomerInitiatedMaintenanceAllowed) $($vmDetails.MaintenanceRedeployStatus.LastOperationMessage)"               
            }
          }
    }
}
```

Link: [Handling planned maintenance notifications for Windows virtual machines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/maintenance-notifications)

---

### Azure Metadata Service

Scheduled Events is an Azure Metadata Service that gives your application time to prepare for virtual machine maintenance. It provides information about upcoming maintenance events (e.g. reboot) so your application can prepare for them and limit disruption. It is available for all Azure Virtual Machine types including PaaS and IaaS on both Windows and Linux.

```
# How to get scheduled events 
function Get-ScheduledEvents($uri)
{
    $scheduledEvents = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Metadata"="true"} -URI $uri -Method get
    $json = ConvertTo-Json $scheduledEvents
    Write-Host "Received following events: `n" $json
    return $scheduledEvents
}

# How to approve a scheduled event
function Approve-ScheduledEvent($eventId, $docIncarnation, $uri)
{    
    # Create the Scheduled Events Approval Document
    $startRequests = [array]@{"EventId" = $eventId}
    $scheduledEventsApproval = @{"StartRequests" = $startRequests; "DocumentIncarnation" = $docIncarnation} 

    # Convert to JSON string
    $approvalString = ConvertTo-Json $scheduledEventsApproval

    Write-Host "Approving with the following: `n" $approvalString

    # Post approval string to scheduled events endpoint
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers @{"Metadata"="true"} -Method POST -Body $approvalString
}

function Handle-ScheduledEvents($scheduledEvents)
{
    # Add logic for handling events here
}

######### Sample Scheduled Events Interaction #########

# Set up the scheduled events URI for a VNET-enabled VM
$localHostIP = "169.254.169.254"
$scheduledEventURI = 'http://{0}/metadata/scheduledevents?api-version=2017-03-01' -f $localHostIP 

# Get events
$scheduledEvents = Get-ScheduledEvents $scheduledEventURI

# Handle events however is best for your service
Handle-ScheduledEvents $scheduledEvents

# Approve events when ready (optional)
foreach($event in $scheduledEvents.Events)
{
    Write-Host "Current Event: `n" $event
    $entry = Read-Host "`nApprove event? Y/N"
    if($entry -eq "Y" -or $entry -eq "y")
    {
        Approve-ScheduledEvent $event.EventId $scheduledEvents.DocumentIncarnation $scheduledEventURI 
    }
}
```

Link: [Azure Metadata Service: Scheduled Events for Windows VMs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/scheduled-events)